# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-insert

So I read the other posts but this question is unique. So this SQL dump file has this as the last entry.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES(2781, 3, '2013-01-04 17:24:19', '2013-01-05 00:24:19'.
```

I'm trying to insert this value to the table...

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES(5, 5, '2005-04-11 09:54:35', '2005-04-11 17:54:35'
```

it gives me the error, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1." So I'm lost on the concept of how the column and row apply here.

Doesn't `2781,3` mean row 2781 and column 3? And doesn't `5,5` mean row 5 and column 5?

Comment: How many columns declared in `wp_posts`?  How many expressions in the `INSERT` (you show only 4, but it is incomplete)?  `2781,3` is simply the first two expressions in the `INSERT`, not row and column numbers.

Answer (score 128):

The error means that you are providing not as much data as the table `wp_posts` does contain columns. And now the DB engine does not know in which columns to put your data.

To overcome this you must provide the names of the columns you want to fill. Example:

```
insert into wp_posts (column_name1, column_name2)
values (1, 3)
```

Look up the table definition and see which columns you want to fill.

And `insert` means you are **inserting a new** record. You are not modifying an existing one. Use `update` for that.

Answer (score 42):

1. you missed the comma between two values or column name
2. you put extra values or an extra column name

Answer (score 24):

You should also look at new triggers.

MySQL doesn't show the table name in the error, so you're really left in a lurch. Here's a working example:

```sql
use test;
create table blah (id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, data varchar(100));
create table audit_blah (audit_id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, action enum('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE'), id int, data varchar(100) null);
insert into audit_blah(action, id, data) values ('INSERT', 1, 'a');
select * from blah;
select * from audit_blah;
truncate table audit_blah;

delimiter //
/* I've commented out "id" below, so the insert fails with an ambiguous error: */
create trigger ai_blah after insert on blah for each row 
begin 
  insert into audit_blah (action, /*id,*/ data) values ('INSERT', /*NEW.id,*/ NEW.data);
end;//

/* This insert is valid, but you'll get an exception from the trigger: */
insert into blah (data) values ('data1');
```

Comment: I completely forgot that I had after insert, after update and before delete triggers on a table in which I added one new column. Tried everything but insert/delete records on the table did not work until I regenerated the triggers. I cannot thank you enough for this answer.

Comment: @rahimv Really glad this helped you! It's a rather misleading error message and caused me a fair bit of consternation before I realized what was going wrong!

Comment: @inanutshellus THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! I HAD FORGOTTEN ABOUT THE TRIGGERS IN MY DB!!!!!! I WASTED ONE WHOLE DAY LOOKING FOR THE ERROR!! I had to revert to my previous github commit and then start making incremental changes to trace the problem and still could not figure it out!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH @inanutshellus!!!!!

Comment: Imagine if someone *else* put in the trigger how much head-scratching it'd take! Why not put the trigger name in the error!? Glad it helped, @DreadPirateAlex I'm up to 14 happy customers! :^)

Comment: My coworker ran into this and were both scratching our heads, and triggers turned out to be the issue. [`SHOW WARNINGS;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html) helped identify the problematic trigger.

Answer (score 12):

MySQL will also report "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" if you try to insert multiple rows without delimiting the row sets in the VALUES section with parentheses, like so:

```
INSERT INTO `receiving_table`
  (id,
  first_name,
  last_name)
VALUES 
  (1002,'Charles','Babbage'),
  (1003,'George', 'Boole'),
  (1001,'Donald','Chamberlin'),
  (1004,'Alan','Turing'),
  (1005,'My','Widenius');
```

Comment: And also this error occurs if a person forgets a comma ( , ) in between two values of the tuple. This is a silly mistake which often is very irritating

Answer (score 9):

You can resolve the error by providing the column names you are affecting.

```
> INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3)
 `VALUES(50,'Jon Snow','Eye');`
```

please note that the semi colon should be added only after the statement providing values

Answer (score -2):

In my case i just passed the wrong name table, so mysql couldn't find the right columns names.