# While deleting :Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to delete a row from a table but while deleting the entry, MySQL is giving me the following error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

the query which is i m executing is a simnple delete query:

```
DELETE from 'tablename' WHERE id=1341
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369252/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: Are there any triggers post delete. The error shouldn't occur for a delete I believe.

Comment: No there is no trigger post delete

Comment: Thanks Sud. There is a trigger which I ignored before. Now the query works fine

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any triggers on delete statement.
You can see you triggers by SHOW TRIGGERS; 
AND if you want to drop one of the triggers DROP [name_of_the_trigger];

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id=1341
```

(without quotes) i guess is the correct answer