# MySQL - Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: mysql

I am creating a content management system application using MySQL. I have an error in my SQL script. The error says:

```
insert into blogposts (title, lede, content, tag, author, created_at) values 
    (
    'Title of a longer featured blog post', 
    'Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.',
    'This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.', 
    'Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.', 
    'World', 
    'Mark', 
    '1553437967526'
    )

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
```

I am aware of [questions with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369252/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1), but I could not solve this issueby using their answers. Here is my entire SQL script:

```
start transaction;

CREATE DATABASE content_management_system;
use content_management_system;

create table blogposts(
    id integer unsigned not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(512) not null,
    lede varchar(512) not null,
    content varchar(10000) not null,
    tag varchar(512) not null,
    author varchar(512) not null,
    created_at integer unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into blogposts (title, lede, content, tag, author, created_at) values 
    ('Title of a longer featured blog post', 
    'Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.',
    'This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.', 'Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.', 
    'World', 
    'Mark', 
    '1553437967526');


create table website(
    id integer unsigned not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(256) not null,
    about varchar(256) not null,
    topId integer unsigned not null,
    leftId integer unsigned not null,
    rightId integer unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

insert into website (title, about, topId, leftIf, rightId) values
    ('CMS Demo', 
    'Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.'
    1,
    2,
    3);

create table users(
    id integer unsigned not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(256) not null,
    password varchar(256) not null
);

insert into users (username, password) values
    ('Mark', 'fubar');

commit;
```

Comment: You are inserting 6 strings plus one number, and your insert statement only specifies six columns?  What isn't clear to you about that error message?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't even know how I could have missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `insert into blogposts (title, lede, content, tag, author, created_at)` you define 6 variables, but into the INSERT you give 7 parameters. That's why the count doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working piece of SQL script:

```
insert into blogposts (title, lede, content, tag, author, created_at) values 
    ('Title of a longer featured blog post', 
    'Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.',
    'This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.', 
    'World', 
    'Mark', 
    1553437967526);
```