# Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have this error

> Error Code: 1136
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
>   INSERT INTO fgm_pastor(
>   matriculePastor,
>   pastorName,
>   pastorSurname,
>   pastorBirthdayDate,
>   birthdayPlace,
>   pastorFathername,
>   pastorMothername,
>   pastorSexe,
>   pastorPhone,
>   pastorEmail,
>   dateConversion,
>   workBeforeBibleSchool,
>   rankProbation,
>   areaOfCalling,
>   nberYearArea,
>   nbreYearDistrict,
>   martialSituation,
>   nationality,
>   pastorAdresse,
>   photoProfil,
>   raisonIndispoMissionnaire,
>   id) 
>   VALUES
>   (
>   'matriculetest3',
>   'nom test',
>   'prenomtest',
>   '2013-09-12',
>   'Dagobert',
>   'mon pere resr',
>   'ma mere test',
>   'M',
>   'phone test',
>   'pastorEmail test',
>   '2018-12-28',
>   'infomaticien',
>   'rank test',
>   'area test',
>   1,
>   3,
>   'Single test',
>   'Cameroun test',
>   'adresse test',
>   'phototest',
>   'RAS',
>   4
>   );

I already indicate values column but nothing works

here is my query please help me

```
 INSERT INTO fgm_pastor(
matriculePastor,
pastorName,
pastorSurname,
pastorBirthdayDate,
birthdayPlace,
pastorFathername,
pastorMothername,
pastorSexe,
pastorPhone,
pastorEmail,
dateConversion,
workBeforeBibleSchool,
rankProbation,
areaOfCalling,
nberYearArea,
nbreYearDistrict,
martialSituation,
nationality,
pastorAdresse,
photoProfil,
raisonIndispoMissionnaire,
id) 
VALUES
(
'matriculetest3',
'nom test',
'prenomtest',
'2013-09-12',
'Dagobert',
'mon pere resr',
'ma mere test',
'M',
'phone test',
'pastorEmail test',
'2018-12-28',
'infomaticien',
'rank test',
'area test',
1,
3,
'Single test',
'Cameroun test',
'adresse test',
'phototest',
'RAS',
4
);
```

here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `fgm_pastor` (
    `matriculePastor` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorSurname` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorBirthdayDate` DATE ,
    `birthdayPlace` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorFatherName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorMotherName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorSexe` CHAR (3),
    `pastorPhone` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorEmail` VARCHAR (180),
    `dateConversion` DATE ,
    `workBeforeBibleSchool` VARCHAR (180),
    `rankProbation` VARCHAR (180),
    `areaOfCalling` VARCHAR (300),
    `nberYearArea` INT (11),
    `nbreYearDistrict` INT (11),
    `martialSituation` VARCHAR (180),
    `nationality` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorAdresse` VARCHAR (300),
    `photoProfil` TEXT ,
    `isActif` TINYINT (1),
    `raisonIndispoMissionnaire` TEXT ,
    `isDelete` INT (1),
    `id` INT (11)
);
```

Comment: I can't see your query. Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369252/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks for the columns **name and work**. Some of your column names are MySQL reserved words and it is better not to use them as column names:

```
INSERT INTO fgm_pastor 
    ( matricule, `name`, surname, birthdayDate, birthdayPlace, fatherName, 
    motherName, gender, phone, email, dateC, `work`, rankProbation, 
    areaOfCalling, nberArea,nbreDistrict, martialSituation, nationality, 
    adresse, picture, raisonIndis, id) 
VALUES ( 'matricust3', 'nom test', 'prenomtest', '2013-09-12', 'Dagobert', 'monperesr', 
    'mamere', 'M', 'phone test', 'pastorEmail test', '2018-12-28', 'infomaticien', 'rank test', 
    'area test', 1, 3, 'Single test', 'Cameroun test', 
    'adresse test', 'phototest', 'RAS', 4)
```

Comment: thank you for answer 
i change those two column name it is still the same error

Comment: Can you upload your table structure? Maybe you are missing some columns

Comment: CREATE TABLE `fgm_pastor` (
 `mleP` VARCHAR (60),
 `pName` VARCHAR (60),
 `pSurname` VARCHAR (60),
 `pBirthday` DATE ,
 `birthdayPlace` VARCHAR (60),
 `pFather` VARCHAR (60),
 `pMother` VARCHAR (60),
 `pGender` CHAR (3),
 `pPhone` VARCHAR (60),
 `pEmail` VARCHAR (60),
 `PConver` DATE ,
 `Pwork` VARCHAR (60),
 `pRank` VARCHAR (60),
 `pArea` VARCHAR (60),
 `pNberArea` INT (11),
 `pNbreDist` INT (11),
 `pMartial` VARCHAR (60),
 `pCountry` VARCHAR (60),
 `pAdress` VARCHAR (60),
 `picture` TEXT ,
 `isActif` TINYINT (1),
 `raisIndisp` TEXT ,
 `isDelete` INT (1),
 `id` INT);

Comment: The names of the columns are not equal in your CREATE statement and in your INSERT statement

Comment: thank you 
i wrote it like that beacause the syntaxe was too long the i can't add it all as à comment

Comment: @RaphaelGloire please do not post `code` in comments