# In JavaFX Error data not going to save on db

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, desktop-application

before the error is occuring ,this task is executing in perfect way.but this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8h9.png)
is occured without not going to changing of any code line.all of my team member have same issue.
im trying to save

```
   private String code;
private String barcode;
private int qtyOnHand;
private double sellingPrice;
private double showPrice;
private double buyingPrice;
private int productCode;
private boolean discountAvailability;
```

these attributes on oder_details table.
this is the part of my db graph
[enter image description here][2]

this code lines shows ProductDetailBoImpl under the bo layer

```
public class ProductDetailBoImpl implements ProductDetailBo {
    ProductDetailDao dao = DaoFactory.getInstance().getDao(DaoType.PRODUCT_DETAIL);

    @Override
    public boolean saveProductDetail(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull ProductDetailDto dto) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return dao.save(
                new ProductDetail(
                        dto.getCode(), dto.getBarcode(), dto.getQtyOnHand(), dto.getSellingPrice(),
                        dto.getShowPrice(), dto.getBuyingPrice(), dto.getProductCode(),
                        dto.isDiscountAvailability()
                )
        );
    }

}
```

this is the interface

```
 public boolean saveProductDetail(ProductDetailDto dto) throws SQLException, 
 ClassNotFoundException;
```

NewBatchFormController class is interface called NewbatchForm.fxml

```
public void saveBatch(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "barcode", baos);
        byte[] arr = baos.toByteArray();

        ProductDetailDto dto = new ProductDetailDto(
                uniqueData, Base64.encodeBase64String(arr),
                Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(txtSellingPrice.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(txtShowPrice.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(txtBuyingPrice.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(txtProductCode.getText()),
                rBtnYes.isSelected() ? true : false
        );

        try {
            if (
                    productDetailBo.saveProductDetail(dto)
            ) {
                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Batch Saved!").show();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                this.stage.close();
               /* Platform.runLater(() -> {
                });*/
            } else {
                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Try Again!").show();
            }

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

ProductdetailDaoimpl is locate under the dao layer.

```
public class ProductDetailDaoImpl implements ProductDetailDao {
    @Override
    public boolean save(ProductDetail productDetail) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return CrudUtil.execute(
                "INSERT INTO product_detail VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                productDetail.getCode(),
                productDetail.getBarcode(),
                productDetail.getQtyOnHand(),
                productDetail.getSellingPrice(),
                productDetail.isDiscountAvailability(),
                productDetail.getShowPrice(),
                productDetail.getProductCode(),
                productDetail.getBuyingPrice()
        );
    }
```

this is the interface of this application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8h9.png)

here is the hierarchy of this application

[enter image description here][2]

the error massege
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8h9.png)

please give some support me to resolve this this application is university project the only part is this one is not working at now.
thank you.

Comment: can you provide the specific error message or stack trace that you're receiving? Additionally, if there are any relevant log files or error messages from your application, please share them as well.

Comment: @DavidTeo now i added brother, sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18369252/6395627)

Comment: As an aside, for any future questions you may ask here, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6395627)